# Unable to log into WeChat Sandbox

Tags: sandbox, wechat

Revisiting a project I've not opened for a month or so I've found that the sandbox account I previously set up cant be accessed, visiting; 
http://admin.wechat.com/debug/cgi-bin/sandbox?t=sandbox/login

Allows me to log in via. the scanning of the QR code but after (seemingly) managing to log in it then gives the error 'Unable to initialize'

Previously this worked I'm wondering if there's been an unpublicised change to the WeChat platform?

Comment: So I've not been able to figure out if/why the wechat.com sandbox service has stopped working for me but the Wexin sandbox service on

Answer (score 10):

So I've not been able to figure out if/why the wechat.com sandbox service has stopped working and if I'm an isolated case or it is a common problem

I did discover that the Weixin sandbox service on https://mp.weixin.qq.com/debug/cgi-bin/sandbox allows me to log in / access the same test app tied to my WeChat account so for others having issues the answer may be to use;

https://mp.weixin.qq.com/debug/cgi-bin/sandbox?t=sandbox/login

Answer (score 0):

Same here! The International sandbox is not letting me in, but the Weixin one works.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. This should rather be a comment. Please take a look at this [Tour](stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to ask or answer questions and to learn more about how stackoverflow works.